# install quercus in glassfish?

Tags: java, php, quercus

i have downloaded the latest quercus 4.0.3 war-file from

http://quercus.caucho.com/

how do you install quercus in glassfish?

i followed this old tutorial for a old quercus version but it didnt work:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2007/03/100_java_quercu.html

has someone successfully implemented quercus in glassfish and could give me some guidance here? and tell me where to put all my php files so it would work?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Glassfish v3 and Quercus 4 installation is easy as

1) log in to GF web-console (assuming default values, it's http://[yourdomain]:4848/)

2) go to Applications menu and click Deploy button

3) upload quercus.war file and set application name and context name to 'quercus'

4) press OK and wait

That's it. You now should see Quercus in application list.

To test, open http://[yourdomain]:8080/quercus/ - you should see Caucho test page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1760/gjxjf/index.html

Did you know that there is a Quercus 7 coming?  It will be bundled with Resin 7 from Caucho Technology.

Comment: This answer should have been posted as a comment.